# Why did I fail this review audit?

Tags: support, review-queues, review-audits, disputed-review-audits

[Here is the audit.](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/5006410) This is a *yes/no* question, so I decided to close it. However, **I failed the review audit**.

Can someone explain this behavior to me?

Comment: Audit questions are chosen at random, once in a while the system will choose one that really should be closed even though it never received a close vote.  So there's a small false-positive rate.  This is annoying but harmless.

Comment: However, that seems like a perfectly good question to me, and I wasn't aware of any policy that yes/no questions weren't allowed.  Do you have a reference?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Even though it reads like it at first sight, I don't think it's necessarily a yes/no question. It's implied that if the answer is "yes", they would want to know how to use reflection and dynamic typing in Swift. And if it's "no", an answer could suggest why it's not needed, and how to get around the lack of the feature.

Most of the audit questions are much more blatantly good or bad, though, IMHO. But I think they let you get away with failing one. I failed one once, and I don't think I got banned from anything. In my case, it said that the post contained offensive content, and I saw nothing in there that looked even remotely offensive to me.

Comment: It's *meh* so -1 to remove it from audit system.